# How to manage security for multiple PC and VM?

Tags: email, webserver, apache, virtualization, iptables

I have a firewall VM which creates I have used to setup subnet for different purposes.

For example: (fake ips, of course)

- 1.1.2.1/24 DMZ
- 1.1.3.1/24 Internal
- 1.1.5.1/24 security/logging

I use dovecot,spamassassin,postfix, and apache on the mail server.

The DMZ has a mail/web server.  The firewall and server use OpenSuSe 13.1 with tumbleweed repository. (newest possible updates)  I have combined iptables and ipset for blocking traffic.

The problem comes in with securing this plus the other computers.  The whole point to a DMZ is to be separate from the internal network.  So if mail/web server has an security issue to report it can't tell anybody because the firewall blocks it.  I then setup a log server (on 5.1 with no internet or internal access), but the quantity of data logged is more than I have time to deal with.

I need something to correlate all the data so when an alert happens on the mail/web server it adds the IP to the ban list on the firewall. Also spamassassin needs to communicate to the firewall also.

I know that others manage dozens of computers so there must be a better solution that doing it manually.  I know there are some hardware solutions, but just the maintenance package cost more than, I can afford.  Hopefully open source projects.  It would be even nicer if it could manage updates across all linux VMs for me.

any suggestions?